# How to model a database to a Dynamic HTML Form?

Tags: html, django, database

I'm trying to make a POST REQUEST to link Dynamic HTML form (when you push the add button, will add another textbox, like in the photo) into Django's default database. Right now I have the following issue, every time I submit data, it only saves the last row. How is the best way to model database and HTML form to save that data ? Any documentation is appreciate it !

[image]

```
Infraestructura.html

{% extends "Portafolio/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}



{% block scripts %}
<script src = "{% static 'Portafolio/scriptinfra.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>    
{% endblock %}



{% block content %}

<form action= "{% url 'infraestructura' %}" method="POST" class="form mt-5" id="infra">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Factibilidad Técnica y Operativa</h1>
    <h2>Análisis de Infraestructura</h2>

    <main class="container">
      <section class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Infraestructura' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Infraestructura">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Tiempo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tiempo">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-2">
          <input name='Costo' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Costo Mensual">
        </div>      
      </section>

    </main>

    <nav class="btn-group">
      <button id='add' class='btn btn-success' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Añadir
      </button>
      <button id='rem' class='btn btn-danger' type='button'>
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i> Eliminar
      </button>     
    </nav>
    <!-- Submit buttom-->
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
      </div>
  </form>
  
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Proyecto(models.Model):
    NombreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ResponsableProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    EvaluadorProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    DescripcionProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Financiamiento(models.Model):
    MontoProyecto = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoPropio = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoBanca = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoPublico = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Beneficio(models.Model):
    Rentabilidad = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Infraestructura(models.Model):
    Infraestructura= models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Tiempo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Herramienta(models.Model):
    Herramienta= models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Equipo(models.Model):
    Personal = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Duracion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class MateriaPrima(models.Model):
    MateriaPrima = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Tiempo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ValorUnitario = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def infraestructura(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        infraestructura = request.POST.get('Infraestructura')
        tiempo = request.POST.get('Tiempo')
        costo = request.POST.get('Costo')

        Infraestructura.objects.create(Infraestructura=infraestructura, Tiempo=tiempo, Costo=costo)
        
    return render (request, "Portafolio/Infraestructura.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getlist` instead of `get` and create all the objects with `bulk_create`

```
def infraestructura(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        infraestructura = request.POST.getlist('Infraestructura')
        tiempo = request.POST.getlist('Tiempo')
        costo = request.POST.getlist('Costo')
         
        infras_list = []
        for i,t,c in zip(infraestructura, tiempo, costo)
           infras = Infraestructura(Infraestructura=i, Tiempo=t, Costo=c) 
           infras_list.append(infras)       
        Infraestructura.objects.bulk_create(infras_list)
```

OR you can make use of [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: I have a question ! If I use Django Formsets (I have never use it before) do I have to make  all the fields from scratch generated by Django Formsets? I wouldn't like to start all over again with my forms :(